# Use of select() in a python client

Tags: python, sockets, select, network-programming

I'm currently building a python client for a project. I know little things about python .. So sorry if my code isn't great ! 
My client works fine, it connects to the server, and "talks" to him , easy parts. But I want to use select like I do in C. 
So for now my client looks like this :

```
p = GetOptions()
mess = MessageClass()
ic = InterpretClass()
cc = CommandClass()
s = None

def send_name_to_server(s):
  var = 'TEAM '
  var += p.getName()
  #var += '\r\n'                                                                                                                                                                                    
  mess.sendMessage(s, var)

def protocol(s):
  rec = mess.readMessage(s)
  if (ic.interpret_bienvenue(s, rec, p) == 1):
    send_name_to_server(s)
  rec = mess.readMessage(s)
  ic.interpret_num_client(s, rec, p)
  rec = mess.readMessage(s)
  ic.interpret_size(s, rec, p)
  var = 'OK'
  mess.sendMessage(s, var)

def main():
  try:
    p.parseOpt()
    if not p.getName():
        print('Exception : You need a name to start')
        sys.exit()
    mc = ModuleConnect()
    s = mc.connect(p.getHost(), p.getPort())
    protocol(s)
    s.close()
  except ConnectionRefusedError:
    print('Exception : The server has refused the connection')
  except getopt.GetoptError:
    print('Usage : client.py -n [NAME] -h [HOST] -p [PORT]')
  except:                                                                                                                                                                                          
    print('Exception : An error has occured')                                                                                                                                                    

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

And my class ModuleConnect looks like this :

import socket

```
class ModuleConnect(object):

  """ Create connexion """

  def connect(self, host, port):
    s = socket.socket()
    s.connect((host, int(port)))
    return s
```

So how does it works ? I parse arguments I received from the command line with the parseOpt method (not important here) then I init my connection with the method connect from ModuleConnect and then I talk with my server with the protocol method. Simple I think ? In C in order to use select I would do something like this :

```
FD_SET(0, &(c->read_fds));
FD_SET(c->sd, &(c->read_fds));
  if (select(c->sd + 1, &(c->read_fds), NULL, NULL, NULL) == -1)                                                                                                                                      
{
  perror("Client-select() error ! ");
  exit(1);
}
if (FD_ISSET(c->sd, &(c->read_fds)))
  read_message_from_server(c);
if (FD_ISSET(0, &(c->read_fds)))
  send_message(c);
```

If my server talks to me first I read what he told me, if not I send the message I got to send to him. But I cannot find a way to do it in python ..

Again sorry, I'm a total noob with python , and even following tutorial I can't find a way.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Shouldn't you be using the SocketServer library?

Comment: There's no use of select in that library, how could that help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to avoid the problem I kept reading and sending (almost) at the same time, and when I read something that I souldn't I just threw it away. So no use of select, and juste read/write.